# Titanium Appcelerator - Entering Date of birth in textfield

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to format my textfield where user will enter his date of birth.

Currently when user starts typing the 3rd character, i am adding "/".

But i need to add "/" when user types the 2nd character.

Please find my code below,

```
$.dobTextfield.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    var dobValue = $.dobTextfield.value;

    dobValue = dobValue.replace(/\//g, '');
    var newVal = '';
    var sizes = [2, 2, 4];

    for (var i in sizes) {
        if (dobValue.length > sizes[i]) {
            newVal += dobValue.substr(0, sizes[i]) + '/';
            dobValue = dobValue.substr(sizes[i]);                   
        }
        else
            break;
    }           
    newVal += dobValue;
    $.dobTextfield.value = newVal;  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Recommendation: Use a Date Picker**

I would recommend that you replace your textfield with a label (possibly styled to look like a textfield if that is important).

I would then add a click event to the label which would display a date picker.
[Date Picker Docs](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker)

You could the update the label's value based on date picker's value.

**Solution to your existing code**

```js
var oldValue;

$.dobTextfield.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    var dobValue = $.dobTextfield.value;

    // this checks to see if the user has removed a slash bu hitting backspace
    // without this the user would not be able to delete a back space
    if (oldValue == dobValue + "/") {
        return;
    }

    var newVal = '';
    var sizes = [2, 2, 4];

    if (dobValue.length == 2 || dobValue.length == 5) {
        dobValue += "/";
    }

    $.dobTextfield.value = dobValue;  
    oldValue = $.dobTextfield.value;
});
```

This will enter the slash when the user types the 2nd character and will also allow the user to delete a slash using the backspace if they need to edit the date.

**Other considerations**

Your current textfield allows the user to enter an invalid date. For example the user could enter a date such as 60/99/2018. Using a date picker would remove the need for such validation.